# Using bootstrap styles for select form element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-select

How to apply bootstrap styles on a `<select>` element. I don't see any demonstrable example using bootstrap css for `<select>` form element.I don't know if that is intentional or bootstrap work well with select element ? please enlighten me.

[image]

Added the `.form-control` style but select element seems like an alien on the form :)

Comment: Add the class .form-control to give it basic Bootstrap styling then change that in your own css as required.

Comment: @BillyMoat please see edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [disabled](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-disabled) demo on the Bootstrap documentation shows a select. Removing the disabled from the fieldset gives you example code:

```
<form role="form">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="disabledTextInput">Disabled input</label>
      <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Disabled input">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="mySelect">Disabled select menu</label>
      <select id="mySelect" class="form-control">
        <option>Disabled select</option>
        <option>Disabled select</option>
        <option>Disabled select</option>
        <option>Disabled select</option>          
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Can't check this
      </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

See in action: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XV8x9/)